# How to run scheduled task in less 1 minutes interval in orchardcms. E.g. in 20 seconds

Tags: scheduled-tasks, orchardcms

I know orchard has its default scheduler running in every minutes. Does it mean that the minimal interval is 1 minutes?
If I want a task to run in every 20 seconds, how can I make it.

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to do every twenty seconds?

Comment: @Hazza twenty seconds is just a example. I want, may be 10 seconds or 30 seconds etc. any way. I want to check my records status in every short interval, less than 1 minutes. If the status is not the expected status. The record need to make a patch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open the file `src\Orchard.Web\Config\Sites.config` to uncomment the `Delay between background services executions` paragraph. Here you can set the interval.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen this before! Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so, i guess this is just some hidden stuff you will discover while searching through the whole Orchard base.